# get data from firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase and I tried some code from the docs that show me how to retrieve data from my DB but I think some things is wrong and I can't get data from database(Models tb) with this code:

```
userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref('Models/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   // ...
});
```

please help me!

Comment: What does `console.log(snapshot.val())` show?

Comment: It's somethings like this:
t {zt: t, Gt: e, Xt: e}

Comment: Is that the output from `console.log(snapshot)` or `console.log(snapshot.val())`?

Comment: it's for `console.log(snapshot)` 
I found my mistake my friend tnx for your tip, I need to `snapshot.val()`